# PPT Map - select state name to color object?

Tags: macros, automation, microsoft-powerpoint

I have map of US States in PPT and each state is an object. We are constantly adjusting this in different sales documents. I hate to use the classic "Americans suck at geography", but I was wondering if there is a way for a user to select the states they want in color X and then the states they want in color y, etc? I'm ok with VBA, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could certainly be done in VBA and with a bit of extra care, could be done in a way that you could use with any map (for example, USA on one slide, midwest states, Ohio counties, western Europe on others).

Each shape (state, county, country) would need to be "tagged". In VBA you can apply tags that are name/value pairs.  They're invisible to the user but VBA could, for example, look at all the shapes on the current slide and collect the ones that have a tag like Name: MapShape, Value: Ohio.  It could put each of the Values (Ohio and the other states) into the left list box on a form; the form code could allow the user to select the state names and move them to the second list box on the form, then, when the user chooses a color and clicks an OK button, sets the fill color of each state on the second list box.

If you decide to have a go at this and run into trouble, post your code and an explanation of the problem in StackOverflow with PowerPoint and VBA tags.

Comment: So, I ended up doing a bandaid using the Selection & Visibility view (ALT+F10). I renamed the drawing objects based on the map bodies they represented (sometimes having to group them) so that it was at least easier to *select* the right region and then apply color/stripe/whatever. I'm still working on the "cool" solution though!